# How to create XML request payload in mulesoft using transform message

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I am trying to build an api that has two HTTP components

-- The first http request acquires an access token from marketing cloud
-- The second HTTP component uses that access token and sets it in a xml payload that goes out to marketing cloud to insert a consumer record in the publication list.

Here is the XMl payload

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Create</a:Action>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://{{org id}}.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">#[payload.access_token]</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Objects xsi:type="Subscriber">
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"></ObjectID>
                <CustomerKey>foobar+subtest@gmail.com</CustomerKey>
                <EmailAddress>foobar+subtest@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
                <Lists>
                    <ID>269</ID>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true">
                    </ObjectID>
                </Lists>
            </Objects>
        </CreateRequest>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

My flow looks like this

[image]

And I am referencing the payload in the last http listener as

[image]

But I get failed: bad request (400).

Same request when I send from POSTMAN, works just fine. I acquire an access_token with and then pass the access_token into the second call, in the request body. What am I missing here?

Comment: From the description what you have given you are getting this 400 bad request from 2nd Http Requestee. And when you send the request from postman it is working fine. Is it possible to paste the second request here which is working from postman. One thing I notice is, in the transform you are not adding that access_token. I am trying to understand where you need to add the access_token. If it is the same request which you pasted is what you are sending in the 2nd Requester, then you need to use Webservice Consume node instead of just HTTP requester since I see that the request is an SOAP Reques

Comment: As general guidance for Stackoverflow please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason. Specifically for Mule flows and configurations, they are internally represented as XML text. Use the XML tab in Anypoint Studio to access the XML and copy as *text* in your question. The XML will contain much more detail.

Comment: Also you should add the logs snippets showing the error from the Mule log, which will usually provide more information about the error and which component is throwing it.

Comment: Finally the title of your question is misleading. The question is about the error you are having.